# How to automatically get abuse email address based on IP address

Tags: email, whois, abuse

Unfortunately I've been the target of a DDoS attack. The attackers are abusing DNS services of others. I'd like to email the owners of these DNS services, but I don't want to manually run 500+ whois lookups. Is there a way / script to automate this (getting the abuse email address based on the IP address)?
If necessary I will write one myself but I'd prefer to use a proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a perl script called abuseEmail that should do what you want. It's at http://abuseemail.sourceforge.net/ .

Comment: Last update is from 2001. Might still work, I'll have a look.

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I did email abuse work, which shows... There are also a lot of tools at www.spamhaus.org, but I'm not sure if they have anything that can be used in a script.

Comment: Just because a tool is old doesn't mean it doesn't do the job well.  The wheel was invented a long time ago - we don't need to reinvent it just because it is old.

Comment: True, dunxd. DNS hasn't really changed that much in the past 12 years. The tool might possibly have problems once the new TLDs kick in, but that's still a few months off.

Comment: [This here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/abuseemail/) says it was updated just a few weeks later after all :)

Comment: Tried it today, doesn't return results but two code warnings. Apparently no longer works.